# How to find the indices of a vectorised matrix numpy

Tags: python, numpy, matrix

I have an ndmatrix in numpy (n x n x n), which I vectorise in order to do some sampling of my data in a particular way, giving me (1 x n^3).

I would like to take the individual vectorised indices and convert them back to n-dimensional indices in the form (n x n x n). Im not sure how bumpy actually vectorises matrices.

Can anyone advise?

Comment: I think it would depend on the way the output of `(1,n^3)` is stored to restore back to the desired output format.

Comment: yes this is my issue. I'm simply using nd.reshape to vectorise the matrix, but I'm actually not sure in which order they are stored

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Numpy has a function `unravel_index` which does pretty much that: given a set of 'flat' indices, it will return a tuple of arrays of indices in each dimension:

```
>>> indices = np.arange(25, dtype=int)
>>> np.unravel_index(indices, (5, 5))
(array([0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4,
        4, 4], dtype=int64),
 array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 0, 1, 2,
        3, 4], dtype=int64))
```

You can then `zip` them to get your original indices.

Be aware however that matrices can be represented as 'sequences of rows' (C convention, `'C'`) or 'sequence of columns' (Fortran convention, `'F'`), or the corresponding convention in higher dimensions. Typical flattening of matrices in numpy will preserve that order, so `[[1, 2], [3, 4]]` can be flattened into `[1, 2, 3, 4]` (if it has 'C' order) or `[1, 3, 2, 4]` (if it has 'F' order). `unravel_index` takes an optional `order` parameter if you want to change the default (which is 'C'), so you can do:

```
>>> # Typically, transposition will change the order for
>>> # efficiency reasons: no need to change the data !
>>> n = np.random.random((2, 2, 2)).transpose() 
>>> n.flags.f_contiguous
True
>>> n.flags.c_contiguous
False
>>> x, y, z = np.unravel_index([1,2,3,7], (2, 2, 2), order='F')
```

Comment: Thank you! And I learnt a little about C and Fortran convention along the way!